# Graphx Label Propagation interpretation

Tags: apache-spark, spark-graphx

I am going to try to run label propagation using the inbuilt algorithm of scala on a graph using Graphx.

I am trying:

```
val labProp = lib.LabelPropagation.run(allGraph,5).vertices.collect.
  sortWith(_._1<_._1)
```

and supposedly I get a graph with vertex attributes containing the label of community affiliation.I am expecting an output similar to this:

```
Array[(org.apache.spark.graphx.VertexId, 
org.apache.spark.graphx.VertexId)] = Array((1,2), (2,1), (3,1), (4,2), 
(5,4), (6,5), (7,5), (8,4))
```

What does the label represent exactly?